# Where are hadoop jar files in hadoop 2?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jar

I am trying to implement one sample word count program using Hadoop. I have downloaded and installed `Hadoop 2.0.0`. I want to do this sample program using Eclipse because i think later in my real project I have to use Eclipse only.

I am not able to find Hadoop related jar files like `hadoop-core.jar` and other required jar files. I searched in all the folders of 2.0 hadoop but couldn't find those files. Those same files are available in 1.0 version of Hadoop but not in 2.0 version. I would like to know where can I get these files?

I am not able to find much information about 2.0 version.

please help

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually, I faced a similar issue in the beginning. Apparently, there is no `hadoop-core.jar` for version 2. You'll have to download the Hadoop [Common](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common) and [MapReduce Client Core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core) jars and use them both. I am sure it'll solve your problems. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** I just updated the links such that people can choose the appropriate version from the repository since we now come way past the initial version 2.

Comment: What about dependent libraries? It causes runtime errors later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763553/hadoop-2-0-jar-files.

Comment: @IgorSevo I think you might need to add some dependent libraries, but the question did not ask for it. Also, if you use `Gradle` for dependency management, it automatically includes the dependent libraries and the code works just fine with the above two jars.

Comment: as mentioned in the below reply. They will be available at `${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common` and `${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/mapreduce`

Answer (score 12):

Including JARs in folders listed below worked for me:

```
share\hadoop\common       
share\hadoop\common\lib   
share\hadoop\mapreduce    
share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib
share\hadoop\yarn         
share\hadoop\yarn\lib
```

Comment: The  slashes have to be forward!!

Answer (score 6):

hadoop-core-${HADOOP_VERSION}.jar is in

```
${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common
```

directory, not ${HADOOP_HOME} directory.

Comment: ${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/common

Comment: simple and good answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Mac on Hadoop 2.6.0:

```
hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
```

or just search ".jar" in the hadoop directory, you can see all the .jar files.

Answer (score 2):

`hadoop-core-{version}.jar` became `hadoop-common-{version}.jar` starting with Hadoop 2+

Answer (score 1):

We can get the jar files from https://mvnrepository.com website.

Example - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

On hadoop 2.7.2, I had to set it to the same as HADOOP_COMMON_HOME.

Answer (score -1):

At below location you can find folder named by distribution which you have installed , inside that there is a jar folder. 
/opt/cloudera/parcels/[cloudera distribution]/jars/

Example : /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.10/jars