# Hadoop 2.0 JAR files

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce, dependencies

I am getting an unexpected error when trying to instantiate a `Configuration` object in my Map/Reduce program.

The error is as follows:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

I am using Hadoop 2.2.0. The program worked fine with an earlier version of Hadoop. However, now I need to write this job submitter for the version 2, and this does not seem to be working.

As a side note, I could not find all the required JAR files for this version. I have read the following solution to a similar problem: [Where are hadoop jar files in hadoop 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188042/where-are-hadoop-jar-files-in-hadoop-2). However, this did not work for me. It fails with the above runtime error.

I tried using older JAR files to resolve these issues, but new error keep occurring.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I am using NetBeans, if that makes any difference from some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by downloading the JAR files from [commons.apache directory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) and from Maven repositories. Each time I added a new JAR to the project, the application crashed with a different error (a different class was not found) until I downloaded all of the JAR files from the Maven repository. After downloading a lot of JAR files from the online repositories, most of the JAR related problems seem to be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Including JARs in folders listed below worked for me:
share\hadoop\common
share\hadoop\common\lib
share\hadoop\mapreduce
share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib
share\hadoop\yarn
share\hadoop\yarn\lib

Answer (score 0):

you can try right-clicking the Project, ->Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Go to your src folder, point to "Native Library", then edit the location to the location of your hadoop native library folder (normally: ~/hadoop-x.x.x/lib/native/"folder-depending-on-your-system")