# Error when trying to write to hdfs: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying a write a file to hdfs using scala and I keep getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
at bcomposes.twitter.Util$.<init>(TwitterStream.scala:39)
at bcomposes.twitter.Util$.<clinit>(TwitterStream.scala)
at bcomposes.twitter.StatusStreamer$.main(TwitterStream.scala:17)
at bcomposes.twitter.StatusStreamer.main(TwitterStream.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I installed hadoop following [this tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/). The code below is what I use to insert a sample file to hdfs.

```
val configuration = new Configuration();
val hdfs = FileSystem.get( new URI( "hdfs://192.168.11.153:54310" ), configuration );
val file = new Path("hdfs://192.168.11.153:54310/s2013/batch/table.html");
if ( hdfs.exists( file )) { hdfs.delete( file, true ); } 
val os = hdfs.create( file);
val br = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( os, "UTF-8" ) );
br.write("Hello World");
br.close();
hdfs.close();
```

The Hadoop version is **2.4.0** and hadoop library version I use is **1.2.1**. What change should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hadoop` and `spark` `version`s should be in sync. (In my case, I am working with `spark-1.2.0` and `hadoop 2.2.0`)

**STEP 1** -   goto `$SPARK_HOME`

**STEP 2** - Simply `mvn build` [spark with the version of `hadoop` client you want](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-buildmvn),

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.2 -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

**STEP 3** - Also spark project should have proper spark version,

```
name := "smartad-spark-songplaycount"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.2.0"

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

### References

[Building apache spark with mvn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-buildmvn)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem using **Hadoop 2.3** and I've solved it adding the following lines to my build.sbt file :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.3.0"
```

So I think in your case you case use the 2.4.0 version.

PS: It also worked on your code sample. I hope it will help

Comment: please give the location of build.sbt file.

Comment: Which build tool are you using? SBT by any luck?

Comment: hadoop2.5.0 and eclipse kepler version.

Comment: Maven, gradle or SBT? Or you don't know what I'm actually talking about?

Comment: I am new in hadoop/hdfs. and also i have no idea about this three tool. but what i was trying to tell you is i want to run java program in eclipse which store data in hdfs but i am stuck in this error. Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4.

Comment: Also i replaced hadoop-client.jar version but error still remain same. If you have any suggestions please help.

Comment: Using a build automation tool is one of the basics of software development. I can't explain to you that here, not in a comment a least. For that you need to do some research over the Internet. Bottom line, to solve your issue you'll need to include the appropriate dependencies in your project. NB: I suppose that your Hadoop cluster in actually running normally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71393/discussion-between-manish-bhadani-and-eliasah).

Answer (score 3):

As said in error message
`Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4` your server has slighly newer version, than your client. You have to either downgrade your hadoop cluster (most likely not an option) or upgrade your client library from `1.2.1` to 2.x version.

Comment: My Hadoop-core lib version is 1.2.1(latest: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/)  and my hadoop-client lib version is 2.4.0. Still I get the same error.

Comment: `hadoop-core` isn't what you want then.  You want some combination of the 2.4.0 libraries which includes `hadoop-common`, `hadoop-client`, ...

Comment: Yep, they have [changed artifact name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15202099/298389)