# org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 5 cannot communicate with client version 3

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to execute hadoop job through web interface written in Java. While copying files from local path to HDFS, I am getting the following error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 5 cannot communicate with client version 3
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Hadoop version: `0.23.11`

Does anyone know exact solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems you have dependency mismatch issue here. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634985/error-when-trying-to-write-to-hdfs-server-ipc-version-9-cannot-communicate-with

Comment: I saw that post but dont know where to find the build.sbt file.