# Not able to start the Master process of Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have set up a three node Hadoop cluster and trying to run Spark using Hadoop's YARN and HDFS.

I set the various environment variables like `HADOOP_HOME` , `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, `SPARK_HOME` etc.

Now, when I try to run the master process of spark using `start-master.sh` , it is giving me some exceptions,the main contents of exception file is below:

```
Spark Command: /usr/local/java/bin/java -cp     /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/*:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/ -    Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host master.hadoop.cluster --port 7077 --webui-port 8080


Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
```

As it says ClassNotFound exception,I am not able to understand how to provide this class, and which Jar to use from which it can pick the class file. Does this jar come as bundled with the Spark download?

Can anyone please help in fixing this issue.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307471/spark-without-hadoop-failed-to-launch

Comment: Where did you get the Spark version from? What's the version?

Comment: I manually downloaded for Spark.apache.org. It is the latest version, the one which comes without bundled Hadoop.