# Spark2.4.6 without hadoop: A JNI error has occurred

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

On my windows machine, I am trying to use spark 2.4.6 without hadoop using -
spark-2.4.6-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12.tgz

After setting the SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME and also SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH with information from the post linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307471/spark-without-hadoop-failed-to-launch#)

when i try to start the spark-shell, I get this error -

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

The link referenced above seems and many others point to SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH , but I already have this in my system variables as -

$HADOOP_HOME;$HADOOP_HOME\etc\hadoop*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\common\lib*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\common*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\hdfs*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\hdfs*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\yarn\lib*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\yarn*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\mapreduce*;$HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\tools\lib*;

I also have this line in the  spark-env.sh of the spark -

```
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(C:\opt\spark\hadoop-2.7.3\bin\hadoop classpath)
```

```
HADOOP_HOME = C:\opt\spark\hadoop-2.7.3
SPARK_HOME = C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12
```

When I tried the spark 2.4.5 that came with hadoop seems to work just fine. This tells me there is something wrong with the way I have my hadoop set up. What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](https://programmerah.com/spark-sql-error-a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-exceptio-24325/).

1. Go to your `~/.bashrc`
2. Add `export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)`
3. Apply environment using `source ~/.bashrc`

[image: Apache Spark environment variables]